# free or delete array of strcut c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I made a simple array of struct I made a function to  implement the array from users input

but I am struggling to find the right way to free or delete elements in the array ;

here is my code for a better understanding

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef struct InfStudent
{
    int id;
    int age;
    int lvel;
}studentInfo;
void addElments(studentInfo *s)
{
    int i=0;


    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        s[i].id = i;
        s[i].age = i * i + 1;
        s[i].lvel = i + i + 2;
    }
}
int studCounter  = 0 ;
void deltetElement(void *studentInfo1 ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "empty " << endl;
        free(studentInfo1);
       }
    }



int main()
{
    int n;int i;


        studentInfo st[2];

    addElments(st);
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        cout<<"enter the Id number of the student "<< endl;
      cin >> st[i].id;
        cout<<"enter the age of the student "<< endl;
        cin >> st[i].age;
        cout<<"enter the level of the student "<< endl;
        cin >> st[i].lvel;
    }
    deltetElement(st);

    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
            cout << "Id of the student   " << i << "\t=" << st[i].id;
            cout << "\t Age of the student    " << i << "\t=" << st[i].age;
           cout << "\tLevel of the student   " << i << "\t=" << st[i].lvel;
           cout<< endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

the output

```
enter the Id number of the student
1234
enter the age of the student
32
enter the level of the student
2
enter the Id number of the student
321
enter the age of the student
2
enter the level of the student
32
empty
```

it is printing empty, but the code still working  like 3 second and then printing empty massage, but I did not understand it does delete or not, or there is a better way to do that;

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: why do you think you need to delete or free anything here? C++ does manage lifetime and memory for you if you just let it.

Comment: Only `free` pointers coming from `malloc`/`realloc`. (and `delete` from `new` and `delete[]` from `new[]`).

Comment: your array has `2` elements, but in `deletetElement` you have a loop with `6` iterations, it just does not matter because you are passing the same pointer to `free` in each iteration

Comment: Not only are you `free`ing the same pointer six (!) times, it's also not a pointer that was returned from `malloc`, and this has undefined behaviour. Don't use `malloc` or `free` in C++, and read about pointers and dynamic allocation in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: or rather read about `std::vector` and keep dynamic allocations for later when you actually need it ;)

Comment: because we have 2 opj of the struct studentinfo, the student info has 3 elements; I made for loop to access both of the studentinfo structs, so the length for each element of the student is 3 *  2 how opj we have

Comment: After you fixed the allocation issues the loop after `deltetElement(st);` would probabaly still print the data you put in, but have _undefined behaviour_, because it would access de-allocated memory. I've seen this expectation a lot here: `free` and `delete` **do not reset, clear or overwrite memory**. They only tell the runtime "I'm done using this part of memory, it may be used for other tasks".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using studentInfo st[2]; it's an array of VALUE types, meaning that studentInfo objects are not allocated in heap, and should not be deleted by free() or delete.

Answer (score 0):

> free or delete array of strcut c++

You create an array with automatic storage. Automatic objects are destroyed and their storage is released *automatically* when the variable goes out of scope. You cannot and you must not "free" them in any way other than by letting the execution proceed to the outside of the scope where the automatic object is defined.

Only thing that may be passed to `free` is a pointer that was returned by `malloc` (or certain other related C allocation functions) and hasn't previously been freed. Since that doesn't apply to what you pass to `free`, the behaviour of your program is undefined. That's bad. Don't do that.

P.S. Don't use `malloc` nor `free` in C++ if you can avoid it (and it can usually be avoided).

> I am struggling to find the right way to free or delete elements in the array ;

The elements of an array are destroyed and their storage released when the array itself is destroyed and its memory is released. There is no way to separate those two.